# QGIS2web OL3 layer search issue

Tags: qgis, javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, qgis2web

Please see my example OL3 map here of threatened ecosystems in South Africa: https://storage.googleapis.com/expanded-line-7365/DM%20selector%20%20with%20layer%20(demo)/index.html

Please use the search box to search for a District such as Eden, Ugu, West Coast, Sedibeng etc.

It is perfect how the search result highlights and zooms to the feature, but what I want to do is change the styling of this. For example I do not want the fill of the selected feature to become blurry, or possibly change the blue border to another colour? I have been searching through all the JS and CSS files but I have not been able to find where this information is set.

**edit**

The closest info I have found is this https://github.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-search-layer/blob/master/examples/control-ol3-search-layer.js

But when changing the stroke or fill values, nothing changes on my map.

Comment: This might help:

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/eogk4r4b/

Comment: Thanks, I will mess around with this and see if I can get anything to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it the following way.
In the qgis2web I activate option “Use debug libraries”.
Of course, option “Mapping library location” is set to “Local”.
As a result, file “ol-debug.js” created in folder “\resources”.
In “ol-debug.js”, the code-text has a part in which you can easily customize everything you need.
Find and edit this block:

```
 * Default styles for editing features.
 * @return {Object.>} Styles
 */
ol.style.Style.createDefaultEditing = function() {
  /** @type {Object.>} */
  var styles = {};
  var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
  var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
  var width = 3;
  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POLYGON] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
      })
    })
  ];
  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.MULTI_POLYGON] =
      styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POLYGON];

  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.LINE_STRING] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width + 2
      })
    }),
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: blue,
        width: width
      })
    })
  ];
  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.MULTI_LINE_STRING] =
      styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.LINE_STRING];

  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.CIRCLE] =
      styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POLYGON].concat(
          styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.LINE_STRING]
      );


  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POINT] = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: width * 2,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: blue
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: white,
          width: width / 2
        })
      }),
      zIndex: Infinity
    })
  ];
  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.MULTI_POINT] =
      styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POINT];

  styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.GEOMETRY_COLLECTION] =
      styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POLYGON].concat(
          styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.LINE_STRING],
          styles[ol.geom.GeometryType.POINT]
      );

  return styles;
};
```

You can do something similar by editing the text in the “ol.js”.
But the code there does not look too obvious.

Comment: Nice. The OP might therefore have some joy searching for "override OpenLayers default feature editing style" to try to find a method which doesn't involve altering `ol.js`.